# Why isn't maven replacing the environment variable for the maven-release-plugin release version?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to use the maven-release-plugin with some environment variables, but I get an issue when I use an environment variable for the release version.
I am executing:

```
mvn release:clean --batch-mode -Dtag=${env.tag} -Dproject.rel.com.mycompany.project:project-root=${env.project.rel.com.mycompany.project:project-root} -Dproject.dev.com.mycompany.project:project-root=${env.project.dev.com.mycompany.project:project-root} release:prepare
```

I am getting:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4:prepare
>   (default-cli) on project project-root: Error parsing version,
>   cannot determine next version: Unable to parse the version string:
>   "${env.project.rel.com.mycompany.project:project-root}" -> [Help 1]

If I change the `${env.project.rel.com.mycompany.project:project-root}` to a specific version, the command will pass.

But as you can see I am using:

```
${env.tag}  
${env.project.dev.com.mycompany.project:project-root}
```

with no issues. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

***Additional notes***:

Environment variables:

```
tag=2.55  
project.rel.com.mycompany.project:project-root=2.55  
project.dev.com.mycompany.project:project-root=2.56-SNAPSHOT
```

My Maven version is:

```
C:\>mvn -version  
C:\>set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m  
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)  
Maven home: C:\Users\John\Documents\apache-maven-3.0.4-bin  
Java version: 1.6.0_25, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.  
Java home: C:\JDK\jdk1.6.0_25\jre  
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252  
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 7):

you will have to use the arguments attribute: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments

So in your context your cmd line will look like this (Note the double quotes as well):

```
mvn release:clean --batch-mode release:prepare "-Darguments=-Dtag=${env.tag} -Dproject.rel.com.mycompany.project:project-root=${env.project.rel.com.mycompany.project:project-root} -Dproject.dev.com.mycompany.project:project-root=${env.project.dev.com.mycompany.project:project-root}"
```

Furthermore, if i remember right the uses of the tokens ${env.X} requires the usage of the property name in upper case (to be verified)

Comment: 1. This only gives the same result as mvn release:clean --batch-mode release:prepare   
2. "...in upper case..." why does ${env.tag} work then?

Comment: now that've read your original post fully, env.tag is correctly resolved because you have set the property "tag" properly in your environment. The others are not because you have set them in your environment with the "env." prefix remove this prefix from the environment property, but keep it in the command line. Hopefully that will sort out your issue.

Comment: "the "env." prefix" was something that I copied unintentionally from the command string. I made an edit on the post. So the same question stands again. Btw, thank you for trying ;)

Comment: I see, no worries. strange that it's not working, i never have any issue using environment variable, but yet i'm only using maven 2. what are those `project.rel.com.mycompany.project:project-root` ? are they properties defined in your pom ? i'm not sure the use of colon ":" is allowed in property names ?

Comment: "i'm not sure the use of colon ":" is allowed in property names ?" the same as before :) The project.dev.com.mycompany.project:project-root=2.56-SNAPSHOT environment variable works. only the release variable doesn't. It can be some sort of bug that appears only for this constellation (of windows version, maven and java versions)

Comment: ok, never seen this kind of declaration with colon character in property names. well the "arguments" attribute as per the cmd line in my post should have helped since it's there for passing attributes to the prepare and perform phases. How do you handle those properties in your pom ? could you show an extract of your pom ?

Comment: First of all, the arguments usages refers to additional arguments "Additional arguments to pass to the Maven executions...". You don't need that if you need to provide the arguments developmentVersion and releaseVersion (which are already available arguments for the maven-release-plugin). Secondly if this approach needs me to provide properties in the pom.xml, it starts to go in totally different direction. I needed to use environment variables! That is the issue.  Try to execute my approach and show "mvn -version" and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the release plugin clears the environment[1]. I doubt it's documented[2], I found out by looking at the source. Farid's answer is a good workaround - it passes the environment value via java properties which are not cleared.

I would have simply commented on Farid's answer but SO doesn't think I'm shiny enough.

1. Why??
2. *Classic maven.*